# Load multiple Entities with Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following construct of a database:
[image]

This Database is created b entity framework core and has the following code structure:

```
        public class Table1
    {

        public Table2 element1 { get; set; }

        public Table2 element2 { get; set; }

        public Table2 element3 { get; set; }

        public Table3 element4 { get; set; }
     }
```

Its necessary for some reasons to add there three Table2 Elements instead of List! But now there is my question:

If i want to load the Table1 Object from database with all child informations i need to do something like this:

```
var myElement = db.table1.include(x=>x.element1).include(x=>x.element2).include(x=>x.element3).include(x=>x.element4).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a possibility to load all childs with something like this:

```
var myElement = db.table1.IncludeAll().FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to load all childs. But you can manage that in one place. You can add and use extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Table1> IncludeAll(this IQueryable<Table1> query)
    {
        return query
            .Include(x => x.element1)
            .Include(x => x.element2)
            .Include(x => x.element3)
            .Include(x => x.element4);
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to adjust what children should be loaded for `Table1` in one place.